# Running asp.net 4.0 with IIS 5.1

Tags: asp.net, iis-5

Can we use asp.net 4.0 with IIS 5.1?

Answer (score 7):

commmand as folllows:

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can run .NET 4.0 on IIS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find a version 4.x entry in the APS.NET tab of your virtual directory in IIS, go to  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263  then follow the link for "Web Developers and Administrators"  and (re-)install the .NET 4 platform on your server machine.